When someone says "piece" can we be 100% sure that it's not a motion picture?
This is a part of the Wikipedia page about Stanley Kubrick. This paragraph describes various freelancing jobs Stanley did as a photographer after finishing highschool.
In 1948, he was sent to Portugal to document a travel piece, and later that year covered the Ringling Bros. and Barnum & Bailey Circus in Sarasota, Florida.
Pretty much all definitions for the word "piece" that I looked up are similar to this one.
a written, musical, or artistic creation.
"a haunting piece of music"(Oxford Languages)
I'm pretty sure that in this case "piece" means a written article but I wasn't able to find anywhere if you can use the word "piece" to mean "a movie". I know that a film is an artistic creation as well but I'm having doubts about this one. Can I use "piece" when talking about a movie?

A "period piece" is likely to be a movie. In the actual context the paragraph tells you that he was a photographer, working for the Magazine Look, and so the "piece" means "article for the magazine"  (for which Kubrick would supply photographs)

This is the home of Mrs Levant Graham (1970) - "cinema verite" piece centering on a Washington , D.C. mother and her large family in the black ghetto.

It's unlikely that a photographer who's a filmmaker is documenting a written article by making a film.

You should check the context. The paragraph is about Kubrick's time as a photographer for Look magazine.  He is documenting (taking photos) to illustrate an article about travel (a travel piece).  Magazines don't generally publish movies, they publish articles.

Don't "check the rest of the article".  This question is about the sentence given.  Every single person reading that sentence per se would assume it meant a travelogue, a film piece.  If I offered this example sentence: "George Lucas first paid job was documenting a piece by Coppola ..." the only possible way to read it would be describing Lucas documenting the making of a film by Coppola (ie, as actually happened IRL).

Bill Kerr is right. These are pictures for a magazine piece (article).

@Yosef Baskin Document = record (something) in written, photographic, or other form.
"the photographer spent years documenting the lives of miners"

In the specific case, it's clear (from the context) that Kubrick was a photographer, and taking still photos for an article (piece) in the Magazine Look.
In general, "piece" is much more rarely used for film, except when forming compounds such as "period piece" (a drama set in the past).  I could imagine combining it with the name of a genre "sci-fi piece", for example.
"Piece" often refers to a short-form artistic creation:  A newspaper article rather than a novel,  a minuet not a symphony.  So I note that this article about Spielberg uses "piece" to refer to some of Spielberg's short films that are part of a compendium work by several directors:

KICK THE CAN is integrated into the larger TWILIGHT ZONE: THE MOVIE narrative, and doesn’t blatantly announce itself as a Spielberg piece.

Here "piece" refers to Spielberg's short film, not the whole movie. It is literally a "piece" of the movie.
But such examples are hard to find.  For whatever reason, movies are not often referred to as "pieces".

?  As you say (A) it's somewhat rare to use "piece" naked without a modifier before it, and (B) "piece," if used alone, tends to refer to a shorter work rather than a longer work.  But all of that applies identically to film or any other form.

There are many obvious examples in the case of feature film directors, if that is what is under discussion; most later-successful directors made short films in college (eg, "Scorsese's A close shave is a great piece..."); episodic TV (ie, 19 minute film "30 minute shows") if made by a feature director would commonly be referred to as a nice piece (or a crappy piece); amongst the many extremely famous  feature directors who are also famous commercial directors, "that's a nice piece" is commonly said of the spots. Films by "art" filmmakers (eg, Warhol's pieces) are often short.

A piece can be a work of any form of art. A painting, a statue, a story, a play, a song, a symphony, a comics, or indeed a movie. When talking about a "piece", the general connotation is that we're probably refering to a standalone work that can be published/performed/exhibited individually (not one canvas out of a triptych, not a song from a musical, not an episode of a series). But whether we're discussing visual arts, literature, music or film is to be determined from context.


When someone says "piece" can we be 100% sure that it's not a motion picture?

Certainly it can mean a movie.
Indeed it normally and more commonly means a movie.
In the actual example, "a travel piece", I assumed it meant a small travel film, aka a travelogue.
The question is about this specific example:

In 1948, he was sent to Portugal to document a travel piece, and later that year covered the Ringling Bros. and Barnum & Bailey Circus in Sarasota, Florida.

You would normally assume that means "a movie" (a "travelogue").
The title of the question is this, "When someone says "piece" can we be 100% sure that it's not a motion picture?"
The answer to that question is "actually the usual assumption would be a motion picture".
The example given in the question is this,

In 1948, he was sent to Portugal to document a travel piece, and later that year covered the Ringling Bros. and Barnum & Bailey Circus in Sarasota, Florida.

Which would suggest a motion picture.
As a curiosity, note that an incredibly famous film, an epitome of "auteur era" filmmaking, was titled Five easy pieces.
I work with film and tv makers every day and it's completely commonplace to use "piece" to refer to some sort of film piece (!) of work, exactly as much so as with musicians, writers, etc.
And now let;'s look at the question as stated at the end of the question:

Can I use "piece" when talking about a movie?

Yes, it is the most common and usual case.

Read the entire context. He was working as a photographer shooting pictures for an article in a magazine.

I direct your attention to the question title; also note my edited answer where I cut and paste the question now three times!
